# Rotate and Translate Canvas Element Specific Location

Tags: html, canvas

I work on canvas elements and i stucked somewhere at rotate canvas element.

With my project user click any location on canvas and generate text via fillText

its ok so far.But when user try to rotate it basicly it fails because i stucked on translate and -translate issue with specific coordinates.I researched on internet all of examples use canvas center. which i cant use that because my canvas size 2406* 2406 and **Generated text must be maintained under user clicked coordinates**.

I hope i  described well because english is not my primary language.
Thanks for ur future helps..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine the canvas as a sheet of grid paper on the page. This grid paper is called the transformation matrix. The top left is the origin (x:0,y:0), with x going to the right and y going down the page. Everything you draw is relative to that point and along its x and y. So drawing text at 200,200 is 200 pixels right and 200 pixels down from the origin (top left).

If you use translate, rotate, scale, setTransform, or transform  you move the sheet of grid paper on the page. Say you translate by 200,200. You have moved the origin right 200 pixels and down 200 pixels.  Now if you draw text at 200,200 it is still relative to the origin of the grid paper, which is now not at the top left. Your text ends up at 400 by 400 pixels from the top left. If you want to draw the text at the same location as before the translate you have to change to coordinates to account for the translation.

The rotate changes the direction of the grid. Rotating by Math.PI/2 (90deg) clockwise results on the gird sitting sideways on the page. Moving in the x direction no longer goes from left to right but from top to bottom.

And scale expands on contracts the grid paper. Scales larger than 1 increase the size of each grid, scales smaller than one reduce the size of each grid.

Using a combination of translate, scale, and rotate allows you to position the grid paper anywhere on the page. When you draw text or anything you always draw it aligned to the grid.

To give an example showing how to draw scaled rotated translated text. Please take the time to understand what is happening. I have thoroughly commented it by if you have questions please do ask.  (Fingers crossed as I hope this works as this is the first time I have tried to use the stackoverflow code snippet thing)

```js
// use matix
var useMatrix = false;  // how to create the transformation

// mouse stuff
var mouse = {
    x:0,
    y:0,
};
function mouseMove(event){  // mouse event handler with firefox mod
    mouse.x = event.offsetX; 
    mouse.y = event.offsetY; 
    if(mouse.x === undefined){ // if firefox
        mouse.x = event.clientX;
        mouse.y = event.clientY;
    }    
}

var ctx;
if(ctx === undefined){  // create the canvas if it does not exist
    var can = document.getElementById("canvasID");
    if(can !== null){
        ctx = can.getContext("2d");  // get the context
        can.addEventListener('mousemove',mouseMove); // add the mouse
    }
}

// some stuff to animate some text
var angle = 0;           // 
var angleDelta = 0.1;    // rate of change for angle
var scaleX = 1;          // to hold scale x and y
var scaleY = 1;
var counter = 0;         // counter used to change scale over time
var counterDelta = 0.1;  // rate of scale change
var scaleFunction = function(){    // function to do scale change
    scaleX = Math.sin(counter)*0.4 + 1;
    scaleX = Math.cos(counter)*0.4 + 1;
    counter += counterDelta;
}

// The drawing function will call the drawing callback after it has
// set the coordinate system to the desired position,rotation and scale.
// set coordinates to 
// translate x,y
// rotate angle in radians 
//              0 is no rotation
//              Math.PI/2 is clockwise 90 deg
//              -Math.PI/2 is antiClockwise 90 deg
//              Math.PI is 180 deg
// scale sx along x
//       sy along y
// ctx the context to draw to 
// drawing the function that will draw
function drawAt(ctx,drawing,x,y,sx,sy,angle){
    if(useMatrix){  // create the transform by hand
        var xdx = Math.cos(angle);   // get the direction of x along the page
        var xdy = Math.sin(angle);
        ctx.setTransform( // completely replace existing matrix 
            xdx * sx, // set the x direction and scale it by sx
            xdy * sx,
            -xdy * sy, // set the y direction @ 90deg of x and scale it by sy
            xdx * sy,
            x,y       // set the origin at x and y
        );
    } else {   // create the matrix by mutiplying existing matrix with translation, rotation and scale matricies.
       // the order of these are important
       ctx.translate(x,y); // multiply existing matrix with this translation
       ctx.rotate(angle);  // multiply the modified matrix with this rotation
       ctx.scale(sx,sy);   // multiply the modified matrix with this scale
        
    }
    drawing(ctx);     // call draw
    
    // restor the transform to default (identity matrix)
    // reset x direction is vector (1,0) from left to right
    //       y                    (0,1) from top to bottom
    // origin is 0,0 at the top left of page.
    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);  // reset the transform to top left
}



// the function to draw. It does not need to now about where it is being draw.
function drawHello(ctx){  // say hello
    ctx.font = "20px verdana";  // all drawing is relative to the origin
    ctx.textAlign = "center";
    ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
    ctx.fillText("Hello planet Earth!",0,-22); // draw above in the y direct -22 pixels
    ctx.fillText("This is an example to help",0,0); // draw at origin 
    ctx.fillText("understand the coordinate system",0,22); // next line is 22 pixels below the top
    ctx.font = "10px verdana";  // change font size
    ctx.fillStyle = "white";    // and colour
    ctx.fillText("Move the mouse over the canvas.",0,44);
}


// clear screen update animation values, and draw the text and what not.
function update(){   // function to update the canvas 
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,ctx.canvas.width,ctx.canvas.height);  // clear the canvas
    angle += angleDelta;     // change the angle
    scaleFunction();         // set the scales
    
    useMatrix = ! useMatrix; // alternate transformation creation method.
    ctx.fillStyle = "red"; // the red center
    // first draw at the center of the canvas
    drawAt(ctx,drawHello,ctx.canvas.width/2,ctx.canvas.height/2,1,1,0); 
    
    // now draw rotating ans scaling around the mouse
    ctx.fillStyle = "black"; // black for the mouse
    drawAt(ctx,drawHello,mouse.x,mouse.y,scaleX,scaleY,angle);
    
    // set time out for the next update.
    setTimeout(update,50); // refresh twenty times a second.
}


// only start if there is a canvas context to draw to.
if(ctx !== undefined){  // make sure there is something to draw to 
    update(); // start rendering;
}
```

```css
.sofCanvas {
  width:400px;
  height:250px;
  border: #000 solid;
  background: #A4A4D1;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvasID" class="sofCanvas" width=400 height=250>time to update your browser</canvas>
```